# Running executable Bash script inside Docker

Tags: bash, docker

I have a Docker container (here you can find the dockerfile defintion https://gist.github.com/ypriverol/05002f5c6477034fef0f05fae25e4f8b) with a

Bash script like:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "Analysing Data"
 exec mono /home/bin/tool.exe "$@"
```

When I execute the container in this way,

```
  docker run -v /home/data:/data_input -i -t toolcontainer nameofscript -i=/data_input/fileinput -o=/data_input/ -m -c=PXD00001
```

I got the error:

> standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Why I get the error and I can't execute my script that wraps the mono tool.?

Comment: Is the file executable?

Comment: Yes is executable I have given to it chmod +x when building the container.

Comment: Does the error come up before the script is started or in the `exec mono...` inside the script?

Comment: Are you trying to run a windows `.exe` file on linux? Can you add more details about your platform, OS, setup?

Comment: Here the dockerfile definition https://gist.github.com/ypriverol/05002f5c6477034fef0f05fae25e4f8b

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please put the information in comments into the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do I have the error? How can I encapsulate the mono tool in the bash script inside the container?

Comment: I have changed my question.